# EXIF-based CLI renaming/querying tool for video/mp4?

Tags: command-line, video, file-metadata, exif

I currently use [exiv2 0.28.2](https://github.com/Exiv2/exiv2) tool to accomplish the same task on my JPEG/TIFF/Raw picture files from the [command line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface). It works really great.

Unfortunately it doesn't work reliably on `video/mp4` media types as it normally reports:

```
corrupted image metadata
```

Of course this can be considered *normal* as there is no mention about support for non-picture (e.g. movie) EXIF media type.

Is there any "*similar*" CLI tool that reliably works on media types like `video/mp4`?

Even just querying would be OK to me as I could wrap that tool around with a script to emulate exiv2 behavior.

Comment: but MP4 files cannot contain EXIF metadata. That's simply not how that container format works; they can contain ISOBMFF metadata and XMP data, but not EXIF. So, if you want to extract the XMP metadata (in contradiction to your question's title): quite a few tools, maybe research getting XMP from MPEG-4 Part 14 files?

Answer (score 0):

[Exiftool](https://exiftool.org) is a command-line tool that can extract and modify metadata in many media formats, including [XMP](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/XMP.html) metadata in video formats such as MP4. This includes filtering and renaming files based on tag values.

Exiftool generally has more features than Exiv2 and better documentation (though both software have a lot of features so I'm sure there's something Exiv2 can do that Exiftool can't do). Exiftool is written in Perl, so its Perl libraries can be used for scripting as well.